# bootstrap page-scroll active color doesn't change

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a free template from Start Bootstrap. (http://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-freelancer/)
When you scroll down at the page, you can see that the menu item that is active has a bit darker background color.
And I want to change the background color of the menu items while they're active but I can't get it to work.

I've tried every option I knew so far to do this.
Could anyone help me with the css needed for this?

Comment: can you post the code of your attempt in a snippet?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/r7fuo2tf/     <-- These are some of the things I've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the rule you have to overwrite:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
   color: #ffffff;
   background-color: yellow; //Use your color here
 }
```

The color you have to change is the `<a>`background (when it is active).

Comment: Exactly what I asked for, it works perfectly. Thanks for your quick reply :)

Comment: You are welcome. The line is in bootstrap.min.css line 11

Comment: You don't need to edit the bootstrap file, just overwrite it in a custom CSS called below the bootstrap file.

Comment: I have pasted it in my custom.css file.

Comment: Then you're all set :)

Answer (score 0):

In your custom CSS place:

`.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #1a242f;
}`

Then you can change the color and background accordingly.

**Make sure your custom CSS is included BELOW the bootstrap file or it will not work.**